# Creating a new .py file in python on a mac but getting [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: python

I have tried to write a python program that creates another python program and when I direct it to where I want it saved it says:

```
`File "/Users/Fredrik/Documents/infinitylock copy.py", line 11, in      createFile
f = open(dest,'w')
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/Fredrik/Documents/python\\'`
```

My entire code is:

```
import time as t
from os import path

def createFile(dest):
    date = t.localtime(t.time())

    name = '%d_%d_%d.txt' % (date[1], date[2], (date[0] %100))

    if not (path.isfile(dest + name)):
        f = open(dest + name,'w')
        f.write('\n'*30)
        f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    destination = '/Users/Fredrik/Documents/python\\'

    createFile(destination)
    raw_input("done")
```

Please answer on how I can get this program to work properly. And resolve the error. Thank you.

Comment: What's with the backslashes?

Comment: You tried to run it with admin privileges?

Comment: What is admit  priviliges... and if I dont use the backslashed it doesn't get that it is a path

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions for 'get this program to work correctly':

What I would do is go through each part of the code, and look up on StackOverflow on how most people use each part. For example, I would use

```
import os
```

instead of

```
from os import path
```

simply because you might later want to use other functions. Its important to keep your code reusable, especially if it gets rid of errors later on.

Answer to 'resolve the error':

Try using forward slashes - I don't know why you have 'python\'
The program is likely throwing an error because you wrote that, an it is not valid and so therefore not permitted. Use .txt or some extension like that. Finally, try to run it with administrative privileges. http://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-With-Root-Privileges-on-a-Mac has a fairly good explaination. Simply open the console, root yourself, then run the program from there.